# Delete All Children on table that REFERENCES itself

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say we have a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(
    Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    [Name] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    ParentId INT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Test(Id)
)
```

In this table, we have a hierarchy of data that may look something like:

```
INSERT INTO Test (Name) 
VALUES ('ABC'), ('DEF'), ('HIJ');
GO

INSERT INTO TEST (Name, ParentId) 
VALUES ('KLM', 1), ('NOP', 1), ('QRS', 2), ('TUV', 2), ('XYX', 3)
GO

INSERT INTO Test (Name, ParentId) 
VALUES ('AAB', 4), ('AAC', 4), ('AAD', 4)
```

How can I delete id 1 and all of its children without using cascade delete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to use an rCTE (recursive Common Table Expression) to recurse through the hierachy. Then you can `JOIN` that data to your table and delete the relevant rows:

```
DECLARE @ID int = 1;

WITH rCTE AS(
    SELECT T.Id
    FROM dbo.Test T
    WHERE T.Id = @ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT T.Id
    FROM rCTE r
         JOIN dbo.Test T ON r.Id = T.ParentId)
DELETE T
FROM dbo.Test T
     JOIN rCTe r ON T.Id = r.Id;
```

Note that unlike some some examples you may have seen, such as where a CTE is used to `DELETE` duplicate rows, a rCTE is not updatable (due to the use of the `UNION`). As such you can't simply perform a `DELETE` operation on the CTE at the end (`DELETE FROM rCTE`) and you have to use it as a `JOIN`.

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=07847ebb94916b5dbb88d027b5337eb9)

Comment: can you please explain this, I don't understand what this is doing?

Comment: My opening sentence explains this, @3xGuy: *"You would have to use an rCTE (recursive Common Table Expression) to recurse through the hierachy. Then you can JOIN that data to your table and delete the relevant rows:"* [Guidelines for Defining and Using Recursive Common Table Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#guidelines-for-defining-and-using-recursive-common-table-expressions)

Comment: If you change the `DELETE` to a `SELECT` you can return the data from the rCTE, @3xGuy . Effectively an rCTe is a self referencing Common Table Expression, and one of it designs is to specifically deal with hierarchical data.